# Is the DC-Link capacitor (C1,C2) necessary in cascaded H-bridge multilevel inverter to achieve more balance and reduce stress on switches?

Tags: power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inverter, h-bridge

What is the purpose of the DC-link capacitor?
The cascaded H-Bridge multilevel inverter topology is free from voltage balancing problems because it does not contain DC link capacitors. but many papers discussed this issue in cascaded H-bridge).

[image]

Comment: Nothing is cascaded in your schematic, it’s just a single H-bridge with decoupling. Can you update your question so that the title matches the content of your question?

Comment: Looks like a 2 cell chain-link full bridge VSC to me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Suppose the load is inductive, like a motor.

T2 T3 are ON, and current flows according to the arrows.

Now T2 T3 turn off, but current in the inductive load does not drop to zero, it keeps flowing according to the blue arrows. So it dumps current into the positive rail.

If the power supply has too much inductance (L) or if it can only supply power (not absorb power) then the current that is dumped into the positive rail has nowhere to go, which causes a fast rise in voltage, which blows the semiconductors.

If there is enough capacitance, then this current is absorbed by the capacitors, charging them, which causes supply voltage to rise a little bit. And on the next cycle, this energy will be reused when T2 T3 turn back on.

Basically, current flowing in an inductive load stores energy in the magnetic field. If the inductor is big enough (say, a motor) it can be quite substantial, and when the bridge attempts to reduce or reverse the current then this energy will have to be transferred from the inductor to somewhere else. If the circuit is not designed to store this energy in a capacitor, or dissipate it safely in a power resistor, then it will be dissipated somewhere unsafe, for example by avalanching the power devices and blowing them up.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see a capacitor across the power supply like this, a safe assumption is that it's there for decoupling.  Fast switching of inductive loads, like this H-bridge switching a motor will generate significant transients.

It's generally good practice to suppress them as close to the source of the transient as possible.  That appears to be the purpose of Cd in the circuit you posted.

Others may leave it out for clarity but in almost all cases where you use such a circuit, decoupling somewhere is needed.

Comment: As close to the *source*? You generally want them as close as possible to the *load*.

Comment: I meant "close to the source of the transient".  I've updated the answer.

Comment: The picture in the OP is certainly not for decoupling -- it's a storage element. That cap will most probably be several hundreds of uF and rated for hundreds of V.

Comment: Well the schematic has changed since I posted this answer but...  What's the difference between a "storage element" and a decoupling capacitor?

Comment: @jwh20 Seeing that both you and winny, above, used the same term, it could my understanding of the term is different: decoupling for me means the high frequency cut-off for noise, oscillations, the usual ~100 nF caps besides the main uF, while the storage are the bulky ones that are meant to store the energy so that it gets delivered the next cycle. I suppose you could argue that a cap is a cap, but not every cap has the same purpose. But this is what I understand. Maybe the meanings are the same and I need to update my English?

Comment: @jwh20 A few orders of magnitude between 50/60 Hz energy storage and decoupling for us of switch transitions.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen In the first schematic OP posted I would just call it decoupling because that's what you normally use it for in everyday full-bridges. In a more MW-range VCS (cascaded or chain-link cells, you don't use for laptop adapters but rather traction, FACTS and HVDC), they are usually called just DC link capacitance or energy storage but they are of course very low ESL to effectively decouple it too.

Comment: @winny Then my English is safe for a while longer. In truth, I would not have formulated my reply as a question, but I remember seeing these caps used (and called) "for decoupling" in a few other places. I think this is similar to the "von Hann" and "Hanning" window (I learned the former) -- someone used the wrong term once, for whatever reasons, and someone else took it from there. Now it's part of too many people's vocabulary to be taken back.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Your English is fine, we are into _semantics_ :-) Oh! Did von Hann invent the Hanning window?

Comment: @winny I hope not! ;-)

Comment: @winny so u said ( they are usually called just DC-link capacitance or energy storage but they are of course very low ESL to effectively decouple it too)
in this case, why do we use dc-link here?

Comment: @Salah Depends. What are your needs? Where is it being used and why?

Comment: @winny Cascaded H-Bridge topology is free from voltage balancing problem because it does not contain DC link capacitors. but Many papers discussed this issue in cascaded h-bridge? so I am confused

Comment: @Salah _"I want to output multiple voltage levels"_ If that's your only final goal I would recommend a function generator, possibly with an amplifier connected to it. Cite your sources. Think about where and how they are used.